# Converting nested list into indented plain text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nested-lists

I was wondering if is there any way to convert the following HTML list into indented plain text, i've tried the following solution with jQuery (but unfortunately, it add a tab character to the `pre.code` html element as well, when it should be only on the `console.log` output)

```js
    function serializeCode() {
     $.each($("pre.code"), function() {
      if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("multiline")) {
       console.log($(this).prepend("\t").text());
      }
     });
    }
```

```html
<style>
    pre.code {display:none}
</style>

    <ul id="list">
    
     <li>
      <pre class="visual">Comando 1</pre>
      <pre class="code">command1</pre>
     </li>
    
     <li>
      <pre class="visual">Comando 2 {</pre>
      <pre class="code">command2 {</pre>
    
      <ul class="multiline">
       <li>
        <pre class="visual">Comando 3</pre>
        <pre class="code">command3</pre>
       </li>
      </ul>
    
      <pre class="visual">}</pre>
      <pre class="code">}</pre>
     </li>
    
    </ul>
```

## Plain text output

```
Comando 1
Comando 2 {
    Comando 3
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I solved it!

> The function below iterate through all `pre.code` elements on the list, and add a tab character (`\t`) on the beginning of elements that have a parent with the `multiline` class.

```
function serializeCode() {
    console.clear();
    $.each($("pre.code"), function() {
        if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("multiline")) {
            console.log("\t" + $(this).text());
        } else {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '';
$.each($('.visual'), function () {
a += $(this).text() + '\n';
});
alert(a);
```

Comment: I consider `console.log()` better than `alert()` in terms of debugging js code, anyways, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I also use same if need to show output multiple times (in loop) but here I want you to see the output without many efforts.

Comment: Wait a minute, your code doesn't indent the plain text output